# clang OpenMP does not support omp_set_num_threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, clang, openmp

I have the following program:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

And I compiled it with `clang -fopenmp` and I got the output

```
Hello from thread 0, nthreads 1
```

Clearly the set number of threads function is not called. Does anyone have ideas about why this might happen?

clang version (installed with apt-get):

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

EDIT: I also tried setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to 4.

EDIT2: I have also installed the Intel runtime for OpenMP.

Comment: Are you using gcc? If so, what flags are you passing, `-fopenmp` must be passed to use OpemMP.

Comment: Have you exported the environment variables specified in the **Using** section here? http://clang-omp.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mike, the problem is that the runtime library gets linked to wrong place. On my system (Fedora), it got linked to gcc runtime libgomp, instead of intel's libiomp.

Check this with running ldd on your executable. It should point to the library you got when you build the runtime library as instructed [here](http://openmp.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You need at least clang 3.7.0 to be able to use OpenMP. Versions < 3.7.0 do not support OpenMP